# Start Jboss with Ant. Command exec doesn't work

Tags: ant, jboss, exec

I try to start JBoss with ant.
When i execute this script :

```
<target name="start-jboss" >
         <exec executable="${jboss.bin.dir}\run.bat" >
                       <arg line="--configuration=Myserver -b localhost" />
         </exec>

</target>
```

JBoss is blocking at this step :

```
 [exec] 15:52:55,373 INFO  [AjpProtocol] Initializing Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-localhost%2F127.0.0.1-8009
```

But when i run the run.bat it works... Its the same when i add spawn="true" in exec.

I think that the problem comes from eclipse...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To run a batchfile use cmd as executable, something like :

```
<exec dir"yourworkingdir" executable="cmd" failonerror="true">
<arg line="/c ${jboss.bin.dir}\run.bat --configuration=Myserver -b localhost"/>
</exec>
```

if `arg line=...` doesn't work, use `arg value=...` for every parameter.

**EDIT :** if you have trouble using the batchfile, why not get rid of using that addtional batchfile and use the [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) straightforward as explained [here](http://shrubbery.mynetgear.net/c/display/W/Starting+JBoss+with+ANT) ?

Comment: Thanks but i have always the same problem

Comment: Yes but i just want to try to understand why it doesn't work. Thanks